# injection "Symbol(router)" not found

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I'm using this simple code with vue js 3,it useally works, But this time i had this error

injection "Symbol(router)" not found.

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

```
<script setup>
const { useRouter }=require("vue-router");


const router = useRouter()

setTimeout(() => {
  router.push('/about')
},6000)

</script>
```

Comment: You didn't init router plugin correctly. The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This is your answer. *Compare* https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html

Answer (score 1):

the solution is to replace "const { useRouter }=require("vue-router");"
with "import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'"

Comment: Hello Sallah, welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you perhaps use Stack Overflow's markdown formatting to make sure the answers are more readable? Check here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help